# Node saving to external folder

Tags: node.js

I'd like to save all files to an external folder outside of my node application. I'm getting an error, `ENOTDIR: not a directory`.

```
backend
  ├──routes
  │    └──savefiles.js
  │
externalFolder
```

How do you write to the external folder?

`fs.writeFileSync('../../externalFolder/report.docx', buffer);`.

Comment: What is the current working directory at the time you call `fs.writeFileSync('../../externalFolder/report.docx', buffer);`?

Comment: savefiles.js directory.

Comment: Is `externalFolder` at the same level as `backend` or a child of `backend`?

Comment: It's at the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `backend` and `externalFolder` are at the same level and the current working directory is the directory containing `savefiles.js`, then you need to up one more level with:

```
fs.writeFileSync('../../../externalFolder/report.docx', buffer);
```

The first `..` gets you to the `routes` directory.  The second one gets you to the `backend` directory.  You need to get to the `backend` parent with the third `..` so you can then reach into the `externalFolder` directory.

Note, you can debug this yourself with:

```
console.log(path.resolve('../../externalFolder'));
```

Also, you can remove a dependence on the current working directory by constructing a path using the module's directory such as:

```
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../../externalFolder/report.docx'), buffer);
```

Comment: I still get ENOENT: no such file or directory, open. Is there a way to check and see if the directory exists. Ie, console.log()

Comment: @bp123 - Well, debug it as I suggested and see what the full path of your relative path is.  Perhaps the current working directory isn't what you think it is.  Also, ENOENT is different than ENOTDIR.  There could be a permission issue.

Comment: @bp123 - I've also suggested a way to remove your dependency on the current working directory.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that `savefiles.js` is the entrypoint module. If I had to guess I'd say the correct relative path without using `__dirname` would be `'externalFolder/report.docx'`, assuming `backend` is a directory in the root of the project.

Comment: @bp123 - So that probably means that the current working directory was not what you thought it was.  The app is apparently launched from something other than where savefile.js is located.